# Recreating relation between two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a 1:1 relation between data that was not an explicit foreign key in the database. E.g.

Table 1 has `a` once, `b` twice and `c` once

```
id value
1  a
2  b
3  b
4  c
```

Table 2 also has `a` once, `b` twice and `c` once

```
id value
5  a
6  b
7  c
8  b
```

I want to create a foreign key from Table 1 to Table 2 when the value is the same:

Expected Table 1 after query

```
id value fk
1  a     5
2  b     6
3  b     8
4  c     7
```

I thought about using JOINs but on `t1.value = t2.value` but those create the cartesian product, and I end up with

```
id value fk
1  a     5
2  b     6
2  b     8
3  b     6
3  b     8
4  c     7
```

How can I populate the `fk` field in such a way that different rows with the same `value` receive have different `fk`?

Comment: Please add what you expect.

Comment: It was already there, but I called it `Table 1 final` instead of `expected`. I hope that clarifies the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `JOIN` your tables based on the row number of each `value` in each table; then you can select the `id` value from `Table2` to set the `fk` column in `Table1`. First, add the new column:

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD COLUMN fk INT REFERENCES Table2(id)
```

Then you can `UPDATE` `Table1` with the appropriate `id` from `Table2`:

```
WITH CTE1 AS (
  SELECT id, value,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY value) AS rn
  FROM Table1
),
CTE2 AS (
  SELECT id, value,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY value) AS rn
  FROM Table2
)
UPDATE Table1
SET fk = CTE2.id
FROM CTE1
JOIN CTE2 ON CTE2.value = CTE1.value AND CTE2.rn = CTE1.rn
WHERE CTE1.id = Table1.id
```

Resultant `Table1`:

```
id  value   fk
1   a       5
2   b       6
3   b       8
4   c       7
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ec206/1)